# How to execute a POST or PUT in ADVANCED REST CLIENT?

Tags: rest, client

I am using ADVANCED REST CLIENT to update information on a website. 
I have been able to get XML data out via the `GET` command. I am trying to either `POST` or `PUT` information through the same format that was returned by the `GET` command. On doing so an error message is returned saying "Access Denied." I have access to the Service account for the website I am working on and have no idea why the `POST` would not respond successfully.

The website has a beta version where any change DATA will not affect the original official Data.

I found [this document](https://eng.ucmerced.edu/people/abardini/abardini/dm_fis/doc/websvc) online that helps me to understand the grammar but does not explain DATA update in detail.

On page 20 of the document linked above you shall discover an example of a `POST` which in my case should be the same but has different results.

Answer (score 0):

Should try out the advanced rest client from android app store http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snmba.restclient